# Using Powershell ServerManager module on Windows 2016 Server

Tags: powershell

I have a module that runs on a Windows 2016 server that requires the `ServerManager` module.  However, `ServerManager` is not available.  There are many examples of installing this for Windows 10 using the [Remote Server Admin](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45520) package but that's only for Windows 10.  Hammer Software has a [good article on adding features and roles](https://www.hammer-software.com/how-to-install-remote-server-administration-tools-rsat-on-windows-server-2016/) in 2016 but it doesn't say specifically which role will add the `ServerManager` module to the global environment.  There are a gajillion roles and features and I added a few but can't seem to get the `ServerManager` module into my global environment.

I've read older things (such as this [SOF question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20686302/powershell-add-windowsfeature-unrecognized/20690012#20690012)) that suggest ServerManager is 32 bit and won't autoload for module dependencies.  Microsoft still [documents it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servermanager/?view=winserver2012r2-ps) for Server 2012 but doesn't say specifically how to install and use it on Server 2016.

Now I'm totally confused.  My module requires `ServerManager` but how do I get that installed/loaded?  If I import the module manually it will work, i.e.:

```
PS F:\> import-module C:\Windows\sysnative\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\ServerManager\ServerManager.psd1
```

But I need this to load automatically based on my module `RequiredModules` directive.

Comment: look at the "powershell FeatureOnDemand" section of this >>> Install RSAT Feature on Demand on Windows 10 1809 and Later | Windows OS Hub — http://woshub.com/install-rsat-feature-windows-10-powershell/

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but I have no Optional Features to install.  The RSAT standalone packages that (presumably) add the features are only for 2010.

Comment: What is Windows 2010? And what makes you say that servermanager isn’t available for Server 2016?

Comment: @DougMaurer, sorry, should be Windows 10.  I updated the question.  I know ServerManager can be used with 2016 but it doesn't seem to be part of the global environment.  It may be part (somewhere) of roles and features but that's my question. I'm not saying it's not available but how do I enable it?

Comment: @AndyJ - arg! i misread your Question. i will go back to lurking ... good luck! [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

To use the Server Manager module, you need to install/enable that RSAT feature.  The Server Manager and its PS module are part of that collection.

Comment: Linking to your own site is fine, but only if you do so where applicable and you also **provide disclosure that the site is yours**. See also [our promotion policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion).

Comment: @Spevacus I think it's just a [signature or tagline](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior).

Comment: @Scratte What good or quality information does the signature provide in an answer? Well, none, on the other hand it is only acceptable to place the blogs if they indicate a document that deals with the specific topic and indicating that it is the property of the OP, otherwise it is considered spam

Comment: RSAT seems to be part of Windows 10, not Windows 2016.  The same features are probably installable through roles and features (see the link above, https://www.hammer-software.com/how-to-install-remote-server-administration-tools-rsat-on-windows-server-2016/) but my question is how to install it.

Comment: @eyllanesc Not sure why you'd consider it spam. I'd consider it misguided and subject of removal by an edit. And a link to the help page to not repeat it on future posts.

Comment: @Scratte The problem is that the user introduces it in all his publications so IMO is spam, I would not say it if it was only in a post or at least until it is pointed out but the OP continues to do so. There are many ways to introduce spam in the publications, many users answer questions of a certain topic to promote their blogs and that is not correct. If the OP wants to promote his blog then use his profile where it is allowed

Comment: @user14915444 - I think you're right, however, RSAT is huge and there are a lot of different roles and features.  Do you know which role and/or feature includes ServerManager?